# Transparently rewrite requests to a subdomain

Tags: iis, rewrite

I would like to rewrite requests to `http://www.mysite.com/foo` to `http://foo.mysite.com` without the user's address bar changing. Using [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) I can do the rewrite, but only if I use the [R] modifier flag which makes the rewrite a redirect. Is there a way for me to transparently rewrite requests to a subdomain?

Here's the rewrite rule I've been testing with:

```
RewriteRule ^/foo/(.*)?$ http://foo.mysite.com/index.html?$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly use [P] instead of [R] which will proxy the connection.

This means that apache fetches the document on behalf of the user.

Comment: We're dealing with IIS here, but I will try the proxy flag. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the docs [What's the Difference between Rewriting and Redirecting?](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/2e820208-c2eb-4d6d-a134-c63f7d41244f.htm#Section1). This will explain the difference whether the client will see a change in address bar or not.

IMO you neither have to put `R` or `P` at the end of your rule.

Comment: When I try without the [R] flag, I get a warning in the logs: "WARNING: Rewriting to a fully-qualified URL. Do you want RedirectRule or ProxyPass?", and the rewrite doesn't work at all.

Comment: In this case I'll keep it with Troy and user61492, use `P`.

Answer (score 0):

This [Article](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/concept.htm) has explained the difference between Proxying, redirection and rewriting.
Agree with Troy, that [P] is the option needed.